# Steps to allow script execution in newer Artifactory versions when "Allow Content Browsing" is enabled?

Tags: artifactory

In the latest versions of Artifactory the setting “Allow Content Browsing” is setup to not allow script execution by design.  That means HTML utilizing JavaScript, for example, does not render correctly.  This KB from Jfrog confirms this is setup is by design and states the following:

"If you’re interested in disabling this security improvement and allowing script execution in newer Artifactory versions, kindly reach out to JFrog Support."

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-blocked-script-execution/

We are using the on prem version of Artifactory with the Pro license level that doesn't include support. Hoping someone that sees this could provide the steps to disable this security improvement on our own.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following properties to the artifactory.system.properties file located at the location $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory
artifactory.repo.browsing.content.security.policy=""

You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox

Kindly perform the Artifactory restart after this change.

Comment: Thank you.  I am making progress but still seeing some rendering issues.

Refused to apply style from .../css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('application/javascript') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Do I need to add an entry into mimetypes.xml for application/javascript?  Is so, what should that entry look like?

Also got his error which might be related to the security.policy setting you had me add?
The Content-Security-Policy directive name '""' contains one or more invalid characters. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

these errors are not related to the content browsing - they are actually bugs in your environment - at least in the sense that newer browsers like chrome are enforcing the use of the proper mime types in their code.

The issue occurs because the client code (in the javascript for example) requests to load a CSS file, for example, and the server returns a header saying it's and html file, or it it tried to load a javascript file and the server returns it with a header stating content type is text/html

This is most likely caused by your the server where artifactory is installed itself, perhaps apache or nginx config issue or a hop between the client and the server (perhaps a nginx server, load balancer or firewall)